# Blazor WASM / Java: Select Text and simulate KeyPress

Tags: java, blazor-client-side

The VOIP-Software Estos has a shortcut feature that I'd like to use in a blazor WASM application.
Basically it goes like this:
User:

1. Select any Text/Telephonenumber => [image]
2. Press 'F8' => [image]

The Estos-client (local pc-installation) reads the selected text from the active page and starts a call with this number.
I need to start the dialing-process via Button, because the user would only have a screen-keyboard and that makes things complicated.
So this button would need to select the text in a specific -Element (or span,...) and simulate the F8-Keypress-Event.

I don't really find articles how to realize that with either Blazor-C# or JavaScript.
Could anyone share information or links with ideas on how to get that done?

Thank you